# How to change the number of cores used in code?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a standalone program with Spark that I want to get the running time results using different number of cores. Whatever I've been trying I am getting the same runtime values!

This is the part of code that I am setting the number of cores before creating a Spark context:

```
System.setProperty("spark.cores.max","96")
```

Total number of cores that I have is 252.

Comment: It's probably worth your while showing us what routine(s) you're using for timing the execution of your program.  Many of the questions of this ilk asked on SO turn out to be the result of mis-measurement rather than of faulty parallel execution.

Comment: I am running standalone application which after finishing the program itself gives total running time. I don't use anything myself to measure! and I am sure about the program that is running correct. run time for 252 cores is 270 second.

Comment: Have you tried -Dspark.cores.max=96 ? Then you are sure, that before jvm start the value is set. In your code check `String oldValue = System.setProperty("spark.cores.max","96")` and check it. Maybe spark set it for you.

Comment: What does your data and RDD flow look like? For instance, if your data isn't very partitioned, adding more cores won't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One suggestion is to try setting it using `SparkConf().setMaster(local[numCores])`. This for example sets it to 4 cores:

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("app").setMaster("local[4]")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
```

See here for details https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.SparkConf

Comment: Well, this only works if you are running on local mode. I doubt she has 252 cores on a single machine.

Answer (score 0):

To complete langkilde answer's, you can use the `spark.cores.max` property and set it on the `SparkConf` (not in the system's properties...) or pass it as a parameter of `spark-submit`. By the way, you can also read the doc : https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/configuration.html.

Not all aspects of Spark are well documented, but configuration definitely is.